# in R, assign a unique id using date (not to exceed specified # of days) and entry name

Tags: r

I have a large data set (~500,000 rows) spanning three years.  I want to add an unique ID to group entry names that repeat for 45 days after the first occurrence. After a block of 45 days, the next time the entry name appears it will be considered another group and receive a different ID.

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
         date=c("2013-5-6", "2013-10-5", "2014-1-1", "2014-4-4",
                "2014-5-1", "2014-8-2", "2014-8-10"),
         plane=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c")
      ) 

       date plane
1  2013-5-6     a
2 2013-10-5     b
3  2014-1-1     c
4  2014-4-4     a
5  2014-5-1     a
6 2014-7-20     a
7  2014-8-2     b
8 2014-8-10     c
```

I want code that will generate an ID like the following:

```
       date plane ID
1  2013-5-6     a  1
2 2013-10-5     b  2
3  2014-1-1     c  3
4  2014-4-4     a  4
5  2014-5-1     a  4
6 2014-7-20     a  5
7  2014-8-2     b  6
8 2014-8-10     c  7
```

As you can see, even though observation 5 and 6 are within 45 days of each other, they have a different ID.  This is because observation 6 is more than 45 days from observation 4 (the start of the second Plane A groupings)

Comment: @Brouwer This is not an easy problem.  Especially since the original poster has over 500,000 observations.

Comment: Does the order of the observations matter?  Or does only the days between dates? (e.g. does it matter that you referred to the 2nd grouping of A?  If the first "grouping" of a was within 45 days of the other group, would this have changed the answer?)

Comment: The order of the observations does matter.  Using Plane A from the example above:  

The code would have to see the first occurrence on 2013-5-6 and label all other occurrences within 45 days as ID=1.  

After going through the first block of 45 days, the code would then have to notice observation 4 and label it and all other occurrences of Plane A as the next available ID (in the example, ID=4)

Observation 6 gets a different ID value because it occurred >45 days after the second occurrence of Plane A and, as such, gets ID=5)

Comment: Ran out of room:

Observation 6 gets a different ID value because it occurred >45 days after the second occurrence of Plane A and, as such, gets ID=5 (even though observation 5 and 6 are within 45 days of each other)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly what you want, but it is a decent start at getting the rolling count (something very hard to do in `R`).  I haven't seen a lot of solutions for the rolling by group function that don't take forever or don't run out of RAM when larger datasets are being used.  I think of you provided a larger example (with input and desired output) I would have a better chance at fully understanding your problem.

```
#Load libraries and download package
library("devtools")
install_github("boRingTrees","mgahan")

#Use the data.table package for speed
require(data.table)
require(boRingTrees)
setDT(df)

#Convert your date from character to date format
df[ , date := as.IDate(date)]

#Perform a rolling 45 count by plane adn then set the ID
df[ , roll.count45 := rollingByCalcs(df,bylist="plane", dates="date",lower=-45,upper=0)]
df[roll.count45 == 1 , ID := .I]
df[ , ID2 := ifelse(is.na(ID),ID[.I+1],ID[.I])]
```